# Cumulative score calculation for traveling salesman without loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am calculating running total of distances for all points covered as given in a day's schedule. Currently this is being carried out through looping over a numpy matrix, as per:

*locSequence= sequence of points to be covered*

*h1 and h2 = any two consecutive points*

*locations = a simple matrix that contains distance between any two points*

```
 for i in range(len(locSequence)-1):
   h1=locSequence[i]
   h2=locSequence[i+1]
   score += numpyMatrix[locations.loc[h1,'idx'],locations.loc[h2,'idx']+1]
```

I was wondering if there is a pythonic way of writing this code, i.e., without looping. Thanks!

Comment: There will always be a loop, whether it's explicit like in your code or hidden inside a `np.sum()` call. Your code looks fine to me, is there any good reason why you are not happy with it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Julien! This code is actually part of a Genetic Algorithm solution and therefore is called many thousands of times. This leads to very high run times, which we are trying to reduce through vectorization of all loops in the code.

Comment: what's numpyMatrix?

Comment: Also it appears that locations is actually a pandas DataFrame; numpy arrays don't have a `loc` method. Can you provide example data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that locSequence is a list of integers ranging in values from 0 to len(locations), so that the distance between any two locations `loc1`, `loc2` is equivalent to `locations[loc1, loc2] = locations[loc2, loc1]`.

Example data:

```
In [ ]: locSequence = [0, 1, 2, 0] #Travel from point 0 to point 1 to point 2 to point 0.
   ...: # locations must be a symmetric matrix with all zero diagonal values;
   ...: # the distance between point x to point x is zero
   ...: locations = np.zeros((3,3))
   ...: locations[np.triu_indices(3, 1)] = np.arange(1, 4)
   ...: locations += locations.T
   ...: locations
Out[ ]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.]])
```

Then, we simply use broadcasting to get all of the distances:

```
In [ ]: distances = locations[locSequence[:-1], locSequence[1:]]
   ...: distances
Out[ ]: array([ 1.,  3.,  2.])

In [ ]: distances.sum()
Out[ ]: 6.0
```